# How to know if application is disabled in Android ICS

Tags: android

In Android ICS we have an ability to disable built-in applications.
Is it possible to know if specific app is disabled or enabled in code?

Comment: What do you want this for? If the browser if disabled, Android will search a new Intent to start a webview. If none is found, Android will Toast that the action is not possible.

Comment: Yes, that might be true.
But I have a crash on launching navigation if Maps is disabled. And in some other apps too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
ApplicationInfo ai = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("your_package",0);
                    
boolean appStatus = ai.enabled;
```

if `appStatus` is `false` then app is disabled :)

Edit:

On Android 11 (API level 30) you also need to tell the manifest which apps you want to gather information from:

```
<manifest package="com.example.game">
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.store" />
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility#package-name

Answer (score 6):

**The Accepted answer may lead to an exception as well**, i.e, `NameNotFoundException` and therefore you may have to construct a flow that silently catches the exception and decide the enabled state(it would actually be a third state, i.e, not-installed).

So, it would be better to find the enabled as well as installed state like this:

```
public static final int ENABLED = 0x00;
    public static final int DISABLED = 0x01;
    public static final int NOT_INSTALLED = 0x03;

    /**
     * @param context Context
     * @param packageName The Package name of the concerned App
     * @return State of the Application.
     *
     */
    public static int getAppState(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String packageName) {
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

        // Check if the App is installed or not first
        Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (intent == null) {
            return NOT_INSTALLED;
        }
        List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if(list.isEmpty()){
            // App is not installed
            return NOT_INSTALLED;
        }
        else{
            // Check if the App is enabled/disabled
            int appEnabledSetting = packageManager.getApplicationEnabledSetting(packageName);
            if(appEnabledSetting == COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED || 
                    appEnabledSetting == COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED_USER){
                return DISABLED;
            }
            else{
                return ENABLED;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29 and check the 'enabled' flag in the returned ApplicationInfo object.