# Check if app is enabled or disabled using package

Tags: android

I want to check if one application is enabled or disabled by the user.

The only thing i know is that i can get this `int`

```
int appstate= this.getPackageManager().getApplicationEnabledSetting("com.example.app");
```

How can i use this int to check if the app is enabled or disabled?

**Example**

```
if(......){//is enabled

}
else{
//disabled
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
ApplicationInfo ai = 
               getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("your_package",0);

boolean appStatus = ai.enabled;
```

Thanks to [Amir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14558066/3884250)

Comment: its for every package ? even for a system app?

Comment: I think yes :) Because there is no distinction between system and application package [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) :)

Comment: One thing to note is that if a system application is disabled, you can not use this API to check its status info.

Answer (score 5):

you also can use these constants as per the developer documentation -
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getApplicationEnabledSetting(java.lang.String)

Returns the current enabled state for the component. May be one of `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED`, `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED`, or `COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT`. The last one means the application's enabled state is based on the original information in the manifest as found in ComponentInfo.