# How to use PackageManager to check if an app is disabled in a method

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers

So i have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342883/check-if-app-is-enabled-or-disabled-using-package) helpful answer, which describes what android parts need to be used to check if an android app is enabled.
I have also read the linked documentation.

```java
ApplicationInfo ai = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("your_package",0);

boolean appStatus = ai.enabled;​
```

Now I want to use this in an app.
As a complete beginner I did not yet figure out how to do this.

So I want to write a method whatShouldWeDo() which checks if the app eu.whoever.whatever is enabled.
In case of enabled it should call the method planA() and if disabled it should call planB().

I did try to do some if - elseif stuff, but I failed to word it in a way that works. Would you be so kind to give me an example of what this would look like?

(So this question is not about finding the PackageManager, but about figuring out on how to actually use it.)

Comment: You should definitely add your if/elseif construct to get a more on the point answer!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should do it...

```
public void whatShouldWeDo(String package) {
    ApplicationInfo ai = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(package,0);

    boolean appStatus = ai.enabled;​

    if(appStatus) { // app is enabled
        planA();
    } else {        // app is disabled
        planB();
    }
}

public void planA(){
...}

public void planB(){
...
}
```