# Android App crashing on Enterprise MDM devices which are blocking access to camera, when trying to access it

Tags: android, mdm

App is crashing on Zebra MDM devices on which camera access is blocked, because of which the app is crashing when trying to access the camera. Any way to check if the camera is accessible beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to Zebra support they pointed out to the following SO link.
[How to know if application is disabled in Android ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538431/how-to-know-if-application-is-disabled-in-android-ics)

ApplicationInfo ai = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("your_package",0);

boolean appStatus = ai.enabled;